# Django not finding environment variables set by Github Actions

Tags: django, docker, github, github-actions

I have a Github Action that creates a Docker image, and the issue I am having is that when I `docker logs backend` I get an error like:

```
File "/usr/src/app/api/settings/common.py", line 165, in <module>
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
```

As part of my .yml for GitHub I have this code which from research should inject the environment variables into my Docker image.

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_backend__production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build -t backend .
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.GLOBAL_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.GLOBAL_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

[image: My Github Secrets]

I am wondering if there is anything obvious that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is it a public repo you can share to fork and perform some tests?

Comment: Putting your AWS credentials into a Docker image like this will compromise them – anyone who has the image can `docker inspect` it to get the environment variables back out.  How and where are you trying to run the image; can you use a different approach to give the container AWS permissions?

Comment: @GuiFalourd it is a private repo.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a private container registry on Digital Ocean, and I am using the image in a droplet. I have more environment variables that I omitted, so if there is a security issue I am not quite sure how to put environment variables in my app.

Comment: Are you trying to bake in the env vars into image or just provide them to container? We can see your `docker build` command, but can you show how you are starting the container?